# Backup configuration page not loading

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I upgraded my app service to Standard a few days ago.  However, when I go to the backup configuration page, it never finishes loading.  I just get the dots across the top of the screen forever.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have checked this issue. Per my test, I found I could not configure my backups for my mobile app on Azure Portal as follows:

[image]

While for web app, I could configure the backups via Azure Portal as follows:

[image]

Then I [Use REST to back up and restore App Service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-csm-backup) and [Use PowerShell to back up and restore App Service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-powershell-backup) to check this issue. After configure the backup for my mobile app, I could see the Configure button on Azure Portal, but when I try to change the backup configuration, I encountered the same issue as you mentioned.

Per my understanding, you could leverage the powershell command [Edit-AzureRmWebAppBackupConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/edit-azurermwebappbackupconfiguration?view=azurermps-4.0.0) for a simple way to edit your Backup Configuration, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-powershell-backup#schedule-automatic-backups) for more details.